# Is the output of Date.toString() always in the same format?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

As the title asks, is the output of `Date.toString()` (more precisely, `Date.toTimeString()`) always in the same format, in all browsers?

I ask this since the [EMCAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.4) says that the "contents of the String are implementation-dependent".

---

I need to make sure of this because I need to format the string by inserting HTML `span` elements as follows:

`(new Date()).toTimeString().replace(" GMT", "<span id='offset'> GMT") + '</span>' );`

This would produce (in Google Chrome v28.0.1500.95) something like

`18:19:26<span id="offset"> GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)</span>`

which I can then style with CSS.

---

Suggestions for better ways to style the output would also be great!

Comment: You already got an answer! It's *implementation-dependent* as you mentioned. So I suggest you not write code based on current implementation's result.

Comment: Although I am late to answer this, I will leave my comments for the benefit of others who land on this question seeking an answer:-  

The spec is clear about this. It reads "The contents of the String from toString() are implementation-dependent," (Refer: ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) If you have to stringize date thena a better alternative is to use toISOString(), which as per the spec is strictly "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" formatted. (Refer: ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In brief, no, toString does not always output the same format.

```
new Date().toString()
```

prints

- "Sat Feb 11 2012 02:15:10 GMT+0100" in Firefox 10
- "Sat Feb 11 2012 02:18:29 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)" in Chrome 16
- "Sat Feb 11 02:18:59 UTC+0100 2012" in Internet Explorer 9

I know these are older browser version, but it shows that it is browser dependent.

However, when using `toTimeString()` it appears it always starts with hours:minutes:seconds[space]...

Therefore, you could instead split the string into 2 portions based on the first [space] with:

[`indexOf(" ")`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Then wrap the second portion with your span

[Moment](http://momentjs.com/) does some string formatting of dates, but it also does not handle your requested offset string very well as it depends on the toString() method.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I'll probably be creating my own date formatter in JavaScript then; Moment.js is a bit too heavy (some features I probably won't use).

Comment: The spec is clear about this. It reads "The contents of the String from toString() are implementation-dependent," (Refer: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2)

If you have to stringize date thena a better alternative is to use toISOString(), which as per the spec is strictly "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" formatted. (Refer: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43)

Answer (score -1):

Moment.js is a nice library for formatting dates in JS. https://github.com/moment/moment

Otherwise yes, you'll end up parsing it yourself as browsers render this differently.